# bash: find can't search folder name with spacing

Tags: bash, find, spacing

Using

```
find . -name "old"
```

can be search folder name with spacing e.g: ./test folder/

but after using find function in find function, just like

```
find $(find . name "old")/*
```

it return
`find: ./test: No such file or directory`
`find: folder: No such file or directory`

what happen? something missing?
Please help with suggestion.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Directories with a white space in its name should either be escaped or enclosed with quotes:

```
$ find . -name 'test folder'
./test folder
$ find . -name "test folder"
./test folder
$ find . -name test\ folder
```

This is because the shell uses a white space as delimiter for commands and arguments (amongst others).

Answer (score 0):

Also, what will happen if find finds 2 matches?

It would be better to use find's exec function to launch the second find:

```
find . -name "old" -exec find {} \;
```